# How to split a repository with subfolders into separate repositories for each subfolder?

Tags: git

I have a local repository that includes multiple projects in separate subfolders, and I want to split it into separate, project-specific repositories without altering the actual folder structure. Here's what the folder tree currently looks like:

```
bigfolder/
    .git/
    project1/
        subfolder1/
        subfolder2/
    project2/
        subfolder1/
        subfolder2/
```

What I want instead is this:

```
bigfolder/
    project1/
        .git/
        subfolder1/
        subfolder2/
    project2/
        .git/
        subfolder1/
        subfolder2/
```

I don't want to delete the top folder or move the project folders out from under it. I just want to have smaller, project-specific repositories that preserve the commit histories of the files in each project's folder.

I tried following the directions in this article on GitHub Docs, [Splitting a subfolder out into a new repository](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository), but when I cloned the `bigfolder/` repository into the `project1/` folder, it copied **everything** inside `bigfolder` into the `project1` folder, including all of the project folders. Using `git filter-repo` deleted the files inside the all newly created project folders except the new project1 folder, but it left the folder tree intact. What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like work for `git filter-repo`. https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`git subtree`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/plain/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) to split a subdirectory into a separate repository. The process might look like this.

1. For each project directory, use `git subtree split` to move the history for that directory into an isolated branch:

   ```
   ref=$(git subtree split --prefix=project1)
   git branch project1-split $ref
   ```

   Repeat this for each project directory. This will split the history for each directory into a separate branch.
2. Now that you have that, you can re-create your directory hierarchy:

   ```
   cd ..
   mkdir new-big-directory
   cd new-big-directory
   git clone -b project1-split ../big-directory project1
   git clone -b project2-split ../big-directory project2
   ```

   This will get you your requested layout. You may want to rename the branches at this point:

   ```
   git -C project1 branch -m project1-split main
   git -C project2 branch -m project2-split main
   ```